# Flexbox order horizontal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to place some elements side by side

```
<div class="artist-wrapper">
    <div class="artist"></div>
    <div class="artist"></div>
    <div class="artist"></div>
</div>

.artist-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.artist {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It works quite well! On small screens (like mobile) the `.artist-elements shouldn't stay side by side but rather among each other. Is there a way to do this by using flexbox?

Comment: What do you mean by *among each other*? You'd probably need media queries....

Comment: One element should below the other. Yeah! But I need the CSS flexbox command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need media queries and then allow wrapping in the parent.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/81d8trag/)

```css
.artist-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.artist {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .artist-wrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .artist {
    flex: 0 0 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="artist-wrapper">
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for media queries, just add min-width: 400px; for child and flex-wrap:wrap; for container. Media queries adds so much more code. It's harder to maintain such mess.

Comment: Really? You want to add a hard-coded value...that's more maintainable...I think not.

Comment: add it with variable... LOL, media queries force to write 2x code for same thing or even more.

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you are after?](http://codepen.io/lili2311/pen/PNpjPM) This is using `display: inline-block`

But here is a [solution using flexbox](http://codepen.io/lili2311/pen/PNpjZM), the property for this is `flex-wrap: wrap`, if you remove `min-width` and `min-height` you can have a more fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `min-width` instead or with mediaqueries.

*(see comments)*

```css
.artist-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.artist {
  flex:1;
  min-width:250px;/* whatever breaking points you look for : here we have for 3 elements a first-breakpoint at 500px then another at 250 */
  min-height: 50px;/* demo purpose use content instead*/
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px gray;
}

/* extra */
.artist-wrapper {
  margin:1em;
}
.artist {
  color:#444;
  font-size:1.5em;
  font-family:'lucida console', courier;
  background:tomato;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.artist:nth-child(odd) {
  background:orange
    }
.artist:nth-child(4n) {
  background:turquoise;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width:100%;/* allows it to shrink on small device , can be set to all of them */
    }
```

```html
<div class="artist-wrapper">
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist">breaks at 250px;</div>
  <div class="artist"> breaks at 500px </div>
</div>

<div class="artist-wrapper">
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist">breaks at 250px;</div>
  <div class="artist">breaks at 500px;</div>
  <div class="artist"> breaks at 1250px;</div>
  <div class="artist"> and so on ... </div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
</div>
```